# how to set shadow for font in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i have to set shadow for the font.If it is possible to set shadow for font.how to set outer-line,outer glow for font.Please help me to set outline or outer glow or shadow for font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want in any meaningful way in Corona. You might have a look at using bitmap fonts. Check out [Text Candy for Corona](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/03/19/new-candy-tool-text-candy-corona-50-coupon-inside). You could make two text objects and have one be the shadow, but it would be a sharp shadow.

Answer (score 3):

```
function YourPage:insertText(text, fontname, size, x, y)                        
  local offset = size / 10                                                      
  local label = display.newText(text, x, y, (fontname), size)
  local shadow = display.newText(text, x+offset, y+offset, (fontname), size)
  label:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255 )                                           
  shadow:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0, 128 )                                           
  self:insert(shadow)                                                           
  self:insert(label)                                                            
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [display.newEmbossedText()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newEmbossedText.html) it should to what you need :

```
local myText = display.newEmbossedText( "hello", 200, 100, native.systemFont, 40 )
myText:setFillColor( 0.5 )
myText:setText( "Hello World!" )

local color = 
{
    highlight = { r=1, g=1, b=1 },
    shadow = { r=0.3, g=0.3, b=0.3 }
}
myText:setEmbossColor( color )
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply.i have fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paint.net to create text with a shadow, then save it to an image file and use it in Corona sdk. Paint.net is free and there are several YouTube tutorials on using Paint.net to create text effects like shadows.